# How to detect a click in a grid's empty / white space

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm looking for the best way to detect a click on the empty part of a vaadin grid.
I came across [this post](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18512370/how-to-detect-a-click-in-a-grid-s-empty-white-space)  but unfortunately it has never been answered.

What I would like to achieve is that by clicking on a row of the grid it enters the editing mode (which already works). As long as the user stays in that row the row should remain in editing mode (already works). When the user clicks on another row, then the current row should (validate and) save the editing. Close the editmode and the new row will enter editing mode (All of which works already).
Now the user clicks on the empty part of the grid and there it should (validate, save and) leave the editing mode.

Clicklisteners on the grid itself fire on the empty part, but also when I click on rows, but that event doesn't contain reference on the area that has been clicked, or at least I didn't find that so far.